# Custom keyboard layout without root

Tags: keyboard-layout, non-root-user, xkb

What are the steps to setting up a custom keyboard layout in X11 without root access?  I know it's possible, based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/896297/512320), but I get `Error loading new keyboard description` whenever I try using my new layout.

In `.config` I have created a `xkb` directory as follows:

```
xkb/
  rules/
    evdev-local
    evdev-local.lst
    evdev-local.xml
  symbols/
    my-us
```

In my `evdev-local.xml` in the `<layoutList>` section I added

```
<layout>
  <configItem>
    <name>my-us</name>

    <shortDescription>my-us</shortDescription>
    <description>English (My US)</description>
    <languageList>
      <iso639Id>eng</iso639Id>
    </languageList>
  </configItem>
  <variantList>
    <variant>
      <configItem>
        <name>mdvp</name>
        <description>English (Modified Programmer Dvorak)</description>
      </configItem>
    </variant>
  </variantList>
</layout>
```

and the `symbols/my-us` file is

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "mdvp" {

    include "us(dvp)"
    name[Group1] = "English (Modified Programmer Dvorak)";

    //             Unmodified   Shift  AltGr        Shift+AltGr
    // upper row, left side
    key <AD01> { [ apostrophe,  quotedbl, dead_acute, dead_diaeresis    ] };

    // lower row, left side
    key <AB01> { [ semicolon,   colon, dead_ogonek, dead_doubleacute ] };

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

I then run

> setxkbmap -I ~/.config/xkb/ -rules evdev-local -layout my-us

and get

> Error loading new keyboard description

Back story: I've been using Programmer's Dvorak, and I like it for the most part, but I want to switch the semicolon and apostrophe back to their positions on US Dvorak, since that works better for my workflow.

I have seen [this tutorial](http://www.gabriel.urdhr.fr/2014/06/06/custom-keyboard/) recommended on SE, and it works on my machine, but I need to be able to use the KDE layout switcher widget so I can switch back to plain English QWERTY when someone else needs to work on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it works if you `-print` and pipe the output to `xkbcomp`:

```
setxkbmap \
    -I ~/.config/xkb/ \
    -rules evdev-local \
    -layout "my-us(mdvp)" \
    -print |
    xkbcomp -I ~/.config/xkb/ - "$DISPLAY"
```

I don’t think there is anything wrong with your layout.  I tried setting
it up with `setxkbmap` directly, but even with the `-verbose` option the
output is not helpful:

```
Warning! Multiple definitions of rules file
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+my-us(mdvp)+inet(evdev)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)
geometry:   pc(pc104)
Error loading new keyboard description
```

This is with the default verbose level.  But even if I set it to 10,
which is apparently the max level, it just outputs “locale is C” as well
as where it tries to look for the rules file, in addition to the above.
It does not output anything more about why it fails to load the keyboard
description.

One of the reasons why I prefer to pipe to `xkbcomp` instead of just
using `setxkbmap` is because the former seems to give better error
messages.

Comment: That does not completely answer the question: If I try to run `setxkbmap -print` afterward, this will not show the right settings ! In my case I really need the `setxkbmap` settings to be modified :(