# Custom/non system included keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout

It seems very strange how keyboard layouts are handled in Linux. There are tons of X11 config files. I don't want to bother with them. I just want to have my keyboard layout on any single terminal I log to. I have already some keyboard config file that normally lives in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` let's say its called `lay` and its not a part of any major distribution, I have it on USB or so.

Now I want to just `setlayout /USB/lay` and force my terminal to use it, without root access, regardles if that is XFCE or Gnome terminal or ssh session. I did not find a way to do so.

I don't want to bother with evdev or anything which normally lives in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules` directory, I just want my layout. Is that possible? If that is totally impossible and I need to go along the lines of [Custom keyboard layout without root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397716/custom-keyboard-layout4564-without-root) how to create a script which will on any platform generate valid `~/.config/xkb` structure which will be in turn accepted by `setxkbmap` and work out of the box in raw terminal, Gnome and XFCE?